# how to put radio buttons in windows installer - deployment project?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment, installation, windows-installer

I've a deployment project of windows installer, with some of prerequisites.

I want to perform some operations while installing the product, for that I need to put 2 radio buttons on installer setup project,

do anyone tell me how can I alter setup screens with new controls provided on canvas ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your article [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taa17f7s.aspx) helped, thanks,

what I did is,
     I applied condition on registry key, and programatically checked if that registry key is installed or not to check which radio button user has selected while installing.

[image: Registry Condition Check]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are talking about a need write a [CustomAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9cdb5eda%28VS.80%29.aspx). [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/vsSetupCustomDialogs.aspx) is how you can create custom dialogs for your setup. Also see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/taa17f7s.aspx) for RadioButtons dialog box.